Background color animation of button element with CSS
I want to animate the background color of a button infinitely using CSS animation (note, this is not CSS transition request). I use the following CSS animation which works on Firefox, but does nothing on Chrome/Edge. Why does it not work on those browsers? How do I fix it?


.entry {
  animation-name: my-anim;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes my-anim {
  from {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
<button type="button" class="entry">Enter data</button>




Simply set an initial background value to nullify the user-agent (browser) style. It can be any valid color.


.entry {
  animation-name: my-anim;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  background: none;
}

@keyframes my-anim {
  from {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
<button type="button" class="entry">Enter data</button>




Add appearance: none; to the button's CSS.
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance
Please note that you will then have to re-style the button according to your requirements.


.entry {
  appearance: none;
  animation-name: my-anim;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes my-anim {
  from {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
<button type="button" class="entry">Enter data</button>




Or you can reset all preset button styles using .entry { all: unset; }


.entry {
  all: unset;
  animation-name: my-anim;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes my-anim {
  from {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
<button type="button" class="entry">Enter data</button>



